# NLog AsyncWrapper and FallbackTarget does not work together

Tags: c#, nlog

I have my custom target defined as follows.

```
namespace TargetLib
{
    [NLog.Targets.Target("TestTarget")]
    public class TestTarget : TargetWithLayout
    {
        protected override void Write(AsyncLogEventInfo[] logEvents)
        {
            throw new ApplicationException("Test");
            foreach (AsyncLogEventInfo info in logEvents)
            {
                DoNothing(info.LogEvent);
            }
        }

        protected override void Write(LogEventInfo logEvent)
        {
            DoNothing(logEvent);
        }


        private void DoNothing(LogEventInfo logEvent)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(logEvent.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

My NLog.config file looks as follows. I define a fallback group and then async wrappers inside it for each target.

```
<extensions>
  <add assembly="TargetLib" />
</extensions>
<targets>
  <target name="defaultTarget" xsi:type="FallbackGroup"
returnToFirstOnSuccess="true">

    <target name="inMemoryTargetAsync" xsi:type="AsyncWrapper" timeToSleepBetweenBatches="1000" overflowAction="Grow">
      <target name="inMemoryTarget" xsi:type ="TestTarget"  />
    </target>

    <target name="fileTargetAsync" xsi:type="AsyncWrapper" timeToSleepBetweenBatches="1000" overflowAction="Grow">
      <target name="file" xsi:type="File"
          layout="${longdate} ${logger} ${message}"
          fileName="${basedir}/logs/logfile.txt"
          keepFileOpen="false"
          encoding="iso-8859-2" />
    </target>
  </target>
</targets>

<rules>
  <!-- add your logging rules here -->
  <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="defaultTarget" />
</rules>
```

I have a simple console application to test this as follows:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Press enter to start logging:");
        Console.ReadLine();
        Logger logger = LogManager.GetLogger("Default");
        for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++)
        {
            logger.Log(LogLevel.Warn, "Test warning" + i.ToString());
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Logging complete. Press enter to exit.");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

The problem that I am facing is that since my custom target throws exception. So I am expecting all my log messages to be in FileTarget. But all log messages do not go into the file. Log messages are being missed.

Also I tried using following NLog.config other way around. First I defined AsyncWrapper and then fallback target as follows. But in this case nothing appears in file as my TestTarget synchronous LogEventInfo method is invoked every time. So no exception occurs and thus it does not fallback. But I want async method of my custom target to be invoked. Although this is dummy target, but in actual target I want to optimize batch writes. Please help.

```
<extensions>
  <add assembly="TargetLib" />
</extensions>
<targets>
  <target name="defaultTarget" xsi:type="AsyncWrapper" timeToSleepBetweenBatches="1000" overflowAction="Grow">
    <target name="fallbackGrp" xsi:type="FallbackGroup" returnToFirstOnSuccess="true">
      <target name="inMemoryTarget" xsi:type ="TestTarget"  />
      <target name="file" xsi:type="File"
            layout="${longdate} ${logger} ${message}"
            fileName="${basedir}/logs/logfile.txt"
            keepFileOpen="false"
            encoding="iso-8859-2" />
    </target>
  </target>
</targets>

<rules>
  <!-- add your logging rules here -->
  <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="defaultTarget" />
</rules>
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the relation between AsyncWrapper and FallbackTarget, I'm trying to find myself which should wrap which, but I can tell you that you need to call `LogManager.Flush()` for the AsyncWrapper to write logs, you may also wrap the whole thing into AutoFlushTargetWrapper, I thinks it's same as via XML conf `autoFlush="true"` like:

```
...
<target name="logfile" xsi:type="File" fileName="${basedir}/logs.txt" autoFlush="true">
```

This wraps FileTarget in AutoFlushTargetWrapper.

Unfortunately I can't advise what would be the correct wrapping order. 
I hope this answer at least point you in to right direction.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However, I was working on this almost a year before. Will try to resolve it based upon your inputs when I get time.